# How to leave states in Sproutcore?

Tags: sproutcore

how is it possible to leave a state in Sproutcore? Actually, I am searching for the equivalent to:

```
MyApp.statechart.gotoState('StateA');
```

Is there another way to leave a state manually instead of controlling it via the `substatesAreConcurrent: NO` property? For example: StateA and StateB are concurrent. StateB has two nested substates: StateBa and StateBb. When I am switching from StateBa to StateBb I want to leave StateA. How is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a statechart:

```
App.statechart = SC.Statechart.create({

   substatesAreConcurrent: YES,

   stateA: SC.State.extend({
   }),

   stateB: SC.State.extend({

      initialSubstate: 'stateBa'

      stateBa: SC.State.extend({
      }),

      stateBb: SC.State.extend({
      })

   })

});
```

Your application is within stateA and stateB simultaneously. In order to transition to some other state from stateA when transitioning from stateBa->stateBb, we must enhance stateA as follows:

```
   stateA: SC.State.extend({

      initialSubstate: 'stateAa',

      stateAa: SC.State.extend({
      }),

      stateAb: SC.State.extend({
      })

   }),
```

The idiomatic way to implement this would be to handle the same event, say "change," in both states like this:

```
App.statechart = SC.Statechart.create({

   substatesAreConcurrent: YES,

   stateA: SC.State.extend({

      initialSubstate: 'stateAa',

      stateAa: SC.State.extend({

         change: function() {
            this.gotoState('stateAb');
         }

      }),

      stateAb: SC.State.extend({
      })

   }),

   stateB: SC.State.extend({

      initialSubstate: 'stateBa'

      stateBa: SC.State.extend({

         change: function() {
            this.gotoState('stateBb');
         }

      }),

      stateBb: SC.State.extend({
      })

   })

});
```

This way, sending the "change" event causes a state transition in both concurrent states. If, however, you are interested in leaving the concurrency you would enhance your statechart like this:

```
App.statechart = SC.Statechart.create({

   stateSuperA: SC.State.extend({
      substatesAreConcurrent: YES,

      stateA: SC.State.extend({

         initialSubstate: 'stateAa',

         stateAa: SC.State.extend({

            change: function() {
               this.gotoState('stateAb');
            }

         }),

         stateAb: SC.State.extend({

            join: function() {
               this.gotoState('stateSuperB');
            }

         })

      }),

      stateB: SC.State.extend({

         initialSubstate: 'stateBa'

         stateBa: SC.State.extend({

            change: function() {
               this.gotoState('stateBb');
            }

         }),

         stateBb: SC.State.extend({
         })

      })

   }),

   stateSuperB: SC.State.extend({
   })

});
```

After receiving the "join" event above, your application would no longer be in concurrent substates, but rather just in stateSuperB.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to leave a concurrent state?

Comment: According to Mike's blog (http://frozencanuck.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/ki-concurrent-states-and-the-pivot-state-error-what-to-do/) gotoState should do the trick.  Are you seeing a particular error?

Comment: If gotoState leaves another state is determined by the substatesAreConcurrent property. But if two states are concurrent, it doesn't leave the previous state, right? I am searching for a method to leave a concurrent state without entering another one. For example: StateA and StateB are concurrent. StateB has two nested substates: StateBa and StateBb. When I am switching from StateBa to StateBb I want to leave StateA. How is this possible?

Comment: I've edited my answer.  I would suggest you add the information from your last comment to the question to clarify.

Comment: I understand your solution and this will work but it is not really satisfying if there is nothing "easy" like a leaveState method. Thank you anyway for your answers.